# mql4 iFractals what does it return? And what is MODE_UPPER & MODE_LOWER?

Tags: mql4

I am trying to create a program where I want compiler to identify a Fractal in the last say Four bars and if it is an UP fractal it should not Buy and if its DOWN fractal it should not Sell.
I want to know how does this mql function iFractal works. Does it return 0,1,2? And does MODE_UPPER mean it is an UP Fractal and MODE_DOWN means it is a DOWN fractal which means better to look for Buy.

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of fractals: Bullish(MODE_UPPER) and Bearish(MODE_DOWN).

If you are interested in finding previous Higher Fractal you need to run a loop like this

```
for(int i=0;true;i++){
    double val=iFractals(NULL,0,MODE_UPPER,i);
     f(val>0){
         Alert(val);
         break;
     }
}
```

You can look at the documentation for understanding the other arguments [iFractals](https://docs.mql4.com/indicators/ifractals)